# Cannot call ClassLoader.defineClass() from its subclass in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, clover

Cannot call ClassLoader.defineClass() from its subclass in Groovy

I am trying to build [OpenClover](http://openclover.org/) on JDK17.

When I run an ant target `clover-core.test`, the test `com.atlassian.clover.ClassInstanceProxyTest` is failed with following log. It says the call of `com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader.defineClass()` cannot be assigned to any method:

```plaintext
Testsuite: com.atlassian.clover.ClassInstanceProxyTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.85 sec

Testcase: testDuplicates took 0.319 sec
Testcase: testClassAndClassloaderHashCollisionForClassesWithDifferentNames took 0.037 sec
Testcase: testNull took 0 sec
Testcase: testDifferentClassloaders took 0.342 sec
    Caused an ERROR
No signature of method: com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader.defineClass() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, [B, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [com.atlassian.clover.ClassInstanceProxy, [-54, -2, -70, -66, ...], ...]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader.defineClass() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, [B, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [com.atlassian.clover.ClassInstanceProxy, [-54, -2, -70, -66, ...], ...]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:193)
    at com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader.findClass(PrecannedClassLoader.groovy:37)
    at com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader.loadClass(PrecannedClassLoader.groovy:16)
    at com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader$loadClass.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at com.atlassian.clover.ClassInstanceProxyTest.testDifferentClassloaders(ClassInstanceProxyTest.groovy:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Testcase: testIdentiy took 0 sec
Testcase: testDifferent took 0 sec
```

[`com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader`](https://github.com/openclover/clover/blob/master/clover-core/src/test/groovy/com/atlassian/clover/util/PrecannedClassLoader.groovy) is a subclass of `java.lang.ClassLoader` written in Groovy. `java.lang.ClassLoader#defineClass​(String name, byte[] b, int off, int len)` is a `protected` method, so I think it should be called property from its subclasses.

I have tried to change the call of `defineClass()` with `super.defineClass()` to call the method on the parent class explicitly, but I got following error:

```plaintext
Testsuite: com.atlassian.clover.ClassInstanceProxyTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.748 sec

Testcase: testDuplicates took 0.299 sec
Testcase: testClassAndClassloaderHashCollisionForClassesWithDifferentNames took 0.037 sec
Testcase: testNull took 0.001 sec
Testcase: testDifferentClassloaders took 0.271 sec
    Caused an ERROR
No signature of method: com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader.defineClass() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, [B, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [com.atlassian.clover.ClassInstanceProxy, [-54, -2, -70, -66, ...], ...]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader.defineClass() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, [B, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [com.atlassian.clover.ClassInstanceProxy, [-54, -2, -70, -66, ...], ...]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:147)
    at com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader.findClass(PrecannedClassLoader.groovy:37)
    at com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader.loadClass(PrecannedClassLoader.groovy:16)
    at com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader$loadClass.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at com.atlassian.clover.ClassInstanceProxyTest.testDifferentClassloaders(ClassInstanceProxyTest.groovy:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Testcase: testIdentiy took 0.001 sec
Testcase: testDifferent took 0 sec
```

### Question

Why the call of `defineClass()` on `com.atlassian.clover.util.PrecannedClassLoader` properly refers `java.lang.ClassLoader#defineClass​()` in Groovy?

Comment: What version of groovy are you using?  There was a recent JIRA issue where a new override in the hierarchy in JDK 16+ changed the super mop method distance. It was fixed in Groovy 4 which is at RC2 as of today.

Comment: The build toolchain for OpenClover seems to use `groovy-all-2.4.15.jar` while running test cases. But the version of Groovy depends on other libraries (ex. https://github.com/openclover/clover/blob/master/groovy/build.xml and https://github.com/openclover/clover/blob/master/common.xml), so I'm not sure how to change the version of Groovy consistently.

Comment: Looks like you have some work to do in the Ant scripts. Groovy 2.5+ has converted the all jar to a pom.  Groovy 3+ is needed for Java 16+ support.